# Wrapping an exception within another exception in OCaml

Tags: exception, ocaml

Can I make an exception which contains another exception in its constructor? I want to throw an exception about what exception happened lower down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
exception Foo
exception Bar of exn
```

Might get problems with printing.

```
Fatal error: exception Bar(_)
```